# Current date with ending time in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the query like this:

```
select cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 110) as datetime)
```

This is returning out put like this:

```
currentdate
-----------------------
2013-07-28 00:00:00.000
```

but I want to get current date with ending time. My expected output is like this:

```
currentdate
-----------------------
2013-07-28 23:59:59
```

Comment: Why? What are you going to do with 23:59:59?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in that case, you need to give your `varchar` that you're converting to more characters!

```
select cast(convert(varchar(30), getdate(), 110) as datetime)
                            **
```

And the question really is: why are you converting the output from `GETDATE()` into a `Varchar` and then back to a `DATETIME` in the first place??

Can't you just use

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

and that's all?

**Update:** OK, so you want to get the current day, but the fixed time of `23:59:59`?

Try this:

```
SELECT
   CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + ' 23:59:59' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: sir i want to get out put date with ending time..i mean my query return value somthing like this:2013-07-28 23:59:59

Comment: while executing your query i am getting my answer only

Answer (score 1):

Either of the below will do it for display purposes;

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, 
          CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))));
```

...or...

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(day, 1,
          DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)));
```

You could also just set a fixed time of 23:59:59, but you'd end up with an invalid time at leap second adjustments (which may or may not be ok)

If you want to use it for comparison purposes, it's better to just use "less than the next date".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the current date with the end time, then you will have to append the end time manually:

`select cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 110) + ' 23:59:59.997' as datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

Just for display (without milliseconds)

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + ' 23:59:59'
```